# (AHK) If statement with GetKeyState not working?

Tags: autohotkey

So I'm trying to create a script that'll scroll left and right while holding the middle mouse button. However, the scroll left and right scrolls regardless if the middle mouse button is held down. It always executes. I need help trying to figure this out.

(I do notice at line 21 there is a bit too much space, ignore that)
Code:

```
; Hold the scroll wheel and scroll to scroll horizontally
; Scroll up = left, scroll down = right

#NoEnv
;#InstallMouseHook

#HotkeyInterval 1
#MaxHotkeysPerInterval 1000000 ; Prevents the popup when scrolling too fast

GetKeyState, ScrollState, MButton

if(ScrollState = U)
{
        ;return
}
else if(ScrollState = D)
{
        WheelUp::Send {WheelLeft}
        return

        WheelDown::     Send {WheelRight}
        return
}
return
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method keeps all normal middle click functionality but simply toggles a variable `state` when pressed. This variable is then checked whenever Wheelup or Wheeldown is used.

```
~Mbutton::
    state := 1
Return

~Mbutton up::
    state := 0
Return

WheelUp:: Send % (state) ? "{WheelLeft}" : "{WheelUp}"
WheelDown:: Send % (state) ? "{WheelRight}" : "{WheelDown}"

/*
The ternary operators are short for:
If state = 1
    Send {WheelLeft}
else
    Send {WheelUp}
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for this. If you could explain what the last two lines mean (especially with the % and ? signs) that'd be nice.

Comment: It uses what is called a ternary operator, which is a shortened if/then/else.  So for the Wheelup, If `state = 1` then send the result `{WheelLeft}` else send `{WheelUp}`. I added to my answer for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Hotkeys, as defined by the double-colon, are not controlled by regular `if` statements.  To make hotkeys *context-sensitive*, you need to use `#If` (or `#IfWinActive` or `#IfWinExist`).  An example from the documentation (*Context-sensitive Hotkeys* section):

```
#If MouseIsOver("ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd")
WheelUp::Send {Volume_Up}     ; Wheel over taskbar: increase/decrease volume.
WheelDown::Send {Volume_Down} ;
```

You can also put regular `if` logic *inside* the hotkey (here's an example from the *Hotkey Tips and Remarks* section):

```
Joy2::
if not GetKeyState("Control")  ; Neither the left nor right Control key is down.
    return  ; i.e. Do nothing.
MsgBox You pressed the first joystick's second button while holding down the Control key.
return
```

Context-sensitivity via `#If` is intended for controlling which application your hotkey is active in.  Regular `if` logic inside the hotkey definition is for arbitrary conditions.  What you are trying to do fits the latter.

In many cases, it is useful to do both.  If you want your left/right behavior only in the browser but not in Microsoft Word, for example, you would use `#If` to limit the hotkey activity to the browser, and then `if GetKeyState(...)` inside the hotkey definition to check whether the scroll button is pressed.